# Update Firestore field inside a RecycleView

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I want to update a field inside my Firestore when OnClick is happening.
The problem is that I don't know how to retrieve id of my actual item, because this is auto-generated. ( I want to update *assignedTo* field ). The structure of Firestore is the following: [image]:

A code snippet with my Adapter of my `RecyclerView` is:

```
public class AvailableTaskListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AvailableTaskListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
public List<Task> taskList;
Activity mActivity;
FirebaseFirestore firestore;

public AvailableTaskListAdapter(List<Task> taskList, Context mContext, FirebaseFirestore firestore) {
    this.taskList = taskList;
    this.mActivity = (Activity) mContext;
    this.firestore = firestore;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public AvailableTaskListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_available_tasks_item, viewGroup, false);
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            //HERE I want to be happening the update of my field.


        }
    });
    return new AvailableTaskListAdapter.ViewHolder(view);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AvailableTaskListAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    viewHolder.tvEmail.setText(taskList.get(i).getUser());
    ...
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return taskList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View mView;

    public TextView tvEmail;
    ...

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;

        tvEmail = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);
        ...
    }
}

public void showDialog(final Activity activity) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_apply_to_task);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

    FrameLayout mDialogNo = dialog.findViewById(R.id.frmNo);
    mDialogNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(),"Cancel" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    FrameLayout mDialogOk = dialog.findViewById(R.id.frmOk);
    mDialogOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(),"Okay" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}}
```

Comment: In which place are trying to get the id?

Comment: I commented the place where I'm trying to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see in your code, you are getting a list of `Task` objects but you're not getting the key of each document. To solve this, you need to keep track of both the keys and values of the documents that are in your adapter. A recommended way to do this is to keep two lists, one with the keys, and one with the values.

So first you add a `List<String>` for the keys in your adapter class like this:

```
private List<Task> taskList;
private List<String> keys;
```

And than change your constructor to accept both lists:

```
public AvailableTaskListAdapter(List<Task> taskList, List<String> keys, Context mContext, FirebaseFirestore firestore) {
//                                                                ^^^^
    this.taskList = taskList;
    this.keys = keys; //Intialize the the second list
    this.mActivity = (Activity) mContext;
    this.firestore = firestore;
}
```

Then when you creste a new object of your `AvailableTaskListAdapter` class, beside the `taskList`, pass also the `keys` list.

```
AvailableTaskListAdapter adapter = new AvailableTaskListAdapter(taskList, keys, mContext, firestore);
```

Basically the list of keys is created in the same way you create the list of values. So when you loop throught the collection to create the list of `Task` object, get also the id like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference tasksRef = rootRef.collection("tasks");
tasksRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            List<Task> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
            List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                Task t = document.toObject(Task.class);
                taskList.add(t);
                String key = document.getId();
                keys.add(key);
            }

            //Create/notify the adapter
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: ok, and if i make onclick in onCreateViewHolder, and use the ID there, it is ok?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can use the id, in every place is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just store document id of the document inside Task object. add a new field like"taskId" to Task Object and when you retrieve task from firebase use document.id
example:

```
db.collection("cities")
    .whereEqualTo("capital", true)
    .get()
    .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
        for (document in documents) {
            Log.d(TAG, "${document.id} => ${document.data}")
        }
    }
```